# postgres create rule on insert do nothing if exists insert otherwise; RETURNING id

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, is it possible to **CREATE RULE** which does nothing if *some* key exists but inserts otherwise. In either case it should return the id of the inserted/skipped row.

I need a rule, so please do not give alternates. I currently have the below rule that does nothing on conflicting inserts and I want to perform an insert with RETURNING id clause but I am getting the below error

```
ERROR:  cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation "fco_assets"
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.
********** Error **********

ERROR: cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation "fco_assets"
SQL state: 0A000
Hint: You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.
```

Below is my current rule

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE table_ignore AS
ON INSERT TO table
WHERE (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
       FROM table
      WHERE table.key::text = new.key::text)) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply use `insert on conflict ...`  and forget about rules?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if it is not possible with rules then ofcourse I can use insert on conflict but I am doing insert from various scripts to the same table and also doing batch insert. Having it as a rule makes it convenient that one does not need to pay attention in every the insert statement about conflict. So should I assume it is not possible with rules ??