# postgres TRIGGER upsert with returning

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

i want an upsert functionality that returns the (new/existing) id of the row.

Linking to my previous question. I asked previously about RULE [postgres create rule on insert do nothing if exists insert otherwise; RETURNING id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846085/postgres-create-rule-on-insert-do-nothing-if-exists-insert-otherwise-returning) but looks like it is not possible.

So I resort to a trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_asset() RETURNS trigger AS $trigger_bound$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO asset(symbol, name, type, status)
    VALUES (NEW.symbol, NEW.name, NEW.type, NEW.status)
    ON CONFLICT (symbol) DO UPDATE SET symbol = EXCLUDED.symbol;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$trigger_bound$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upsert_asset_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON asset
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE upsert_asset();
```

I tested the above and works. So my questions are

1. Is this trigger a correct way to achieve this functionality? Any race conditions/performance issues that i should know about?
2. How can I generalize this query, by not giving the column names? asset(symbol, name, type, status). i do not want to pay attention to this rule every time I change my table. Is it possible to say NEW.* or column.* or something? What psuedorelations are available to achieve this? Please note there are some default columns too. So how does NEW.default_column get a value incase the insert statement has left that column in the insert statement?

Thanks,

Comment: It is unclear what "this functionality" is that you are trying to achieve, because the trigger is completely nonsensical. Can you describe what you want to do?

Comment: This trigger will not work. Suppose there is NO conflict. Your trigger fires because you issued an insert, then the trigger issues an insert to the same table - which fires the trigger. Which inserts ... into a never ending cycle. As for getting default values when the column not in the column list it is exactly that fact causing the default to be used. It the column it in the list that value is used - even if NULL is specified.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The first line describes what i want but maybe you missed it. So here it is **i want an upsert functionality that returns the (new/existing) id of the row.**  Why I need it is because Firstly, I have to insert in a table from various files/scripts. Secondly, I do not want to handle the duplicate_key exception on insert. For this reason I want to put a Rule/Trigger on the table itself to take care of this.

Comment: @Belayer, I read about this infinite recursion, but actually this works. I think the recursion is a problem in Rule, but maybe not the same effect in a Trigger. I can just say that it works and am no psql expert. Maybe you can give it a try to disprove me ? Or maybe you know the difference in between a trigger and a Rule?

Comment: @user4772933 and what is wrong with `RETURNING id`? If you want to `DO NOTHING` you might instead just `DO UPDATE SET id = EXCLUDED.id`. No triggers, no rules, just single `INSERT`.